# How to feed speech recognizer the list of words to look into

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Is there any way to tell android's speech recognizer to catch the words only from the contacts list or any predefined list? For example: I want the user to speak a name and rather than looking the useless words, speech recognizer try to find the match from the contacts list.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Grammar Lists that is what you are referring to. Some speech recognition software automatically supports it. Another solution would be that certain speech recognition software will provide a list of possibile interpretations and you can match a grammar list to the return results. Look up the speech recognition API and match it with an array of the names you want it to compare against.

Comment: nopes, I want the speech recognizer API itself to recognize from the predefined list rather than me looking for all possible options and do the matching..I want it just like how voice commands pick the contatcs..